# How to achieve compile time polymorphism of several functions?

Tags: c++, templates

It seems I should to use function as a template argument, but it cannot be done in such way.

The header file looks like this:

```
foo_out_type foo(foo_in_type input);
baz_out_type bar(bar_in_type input);

template<typename T_IN, typename T_OUT>
void do_list(const vector<T_IN>& input,
             vector<T_OUT>& output);

// I want to specialize the template code at compile time
// So the users don't need to compile the code everytime
template<>
void do_list<foo_in_type, foo_out_type>(const vector<foo_in_type>& input,
                                        vector<foo_out_type>& output);

template<>
void do_list<bar_in_type, bar_out_type>(const vector<bar_in_type>& input,
                                        vector<bar_out_type>& output);
```

The implementation file looks like this:

```
template<typename T_IN, typename T_OUT, typename T_FUNC>
void __do_list_impl__(const vector<T_IN>& input,
                      vector<T_OUT>& output)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
        output.push_back(T_FUNC(input[i]));
}

template<>
void do_list<foo_in_type, foo_out_type>(const vector<foo_in_type>& input,
                                        vector<foo_out_type>& output)
{
    __do_list_impl__<foo_in_type, foo_out_type, do_foo>(input, output);
}

template<>
void do_list<bar_in_type, bar_out_type>(const vector<bar_in_type>& input,
                                        vector<bar_out_type>& output)
{
    __do_list_impl__<bar_in_type, bar_out_type, do_bar>(input, output);
}
```

The key is: I don't want to write the implementation several times, as the actual code is much more complex than this. However, the function cannot be passed as an template argument.

So, how should I work around this?

Comment: "the function cannot be passed as an template argument" - isn't that precisely what `T_FUNC` *is* ? And unless I missed something (not unlikely) isn't this a reinvention of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Comment: Names beginning with double underscore are [reserved for implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use functor instead of a function.

Instead of declaring your body function as:

```
T_OUT do_foo(T_IN& input) {
  //your job
}
```

declare it as an object type:

```
class do_foo {
  public:
    T_OUT operator()(T_IN& input) {
     //place your job code here
  }
};
```

Then change your do_list implementation from:

```
template<typename T_IN, typename T_OUT, typename T_FUNC>
void __do_list_impl__(const vector<T_IN>& input,
                      vector<T_OUT>& output)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
        output.push_back(T_FUNC(input[i]));
}
```

to:

```
template<typename T_IN, typename T_OUT, typename T_FUNCTOR>
void __do_list_impl__(const vector<T_IN>& input,
                      vector<T_OUT>& output)
{
    T_FUNCTOR myFunctor;
    for (size_t i=0; i<input.size(); i++)
        output.push_back(myFunctor(input[i]));
}
```

Obviously create a new class also for the "do_bar" function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have a small number of specialized versions of `do_list<...>()`...

In your header:

1. Specialize different versions of `do_list<...>()` to call different
   *non-template* helper functions `do_list_impl1()`, `do_list_impl2()`, ...
2. Also, declare non-template functions `do_list_impl1()`, `do_list_impl2()`, ...

In your implementation file:

1. Include the definition for the template function `__do_list_impl__()`
2. Define `do_list_impl1()` et al to just call `__do_list_impl__()` with appropriate template arguments.